# Unable to close session using telethon due to "session too new"

Tags: python, telegram

I'm trying to write a simple script to close an opened session using [Telethon](https://pypi.org/project/Telethon/) lib:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types
import time

api_id = "YYYY"
api_hash = "XXXXX"

client = TelegramClient('@example', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

#With this I can get all the necesary info about current sessions
result = client(functions.account.GetAuthorizationsRequest())
print(result.stringify())

#With this I should be able to close the sessions using it's hash:
result = client(functions.account.ResetAuthorizationRequest(hash=-123456789101112))
print(result)
```

But I get this error:

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FreshResetAuthorisationForbiddenError:
> The current session is too new and cannot be used to reset other
> authorisations yet (caused by ResetAuthorizationRequest)

I initialized the session like 1h ago; I tried put some time.sleep before the **ResetAuthorizationRequest**, but that didn't did the trick. What should I do in order to close a session? Should I wait more? In that case, what's the aproximated time I need to wait?

Comment: You can't logout other sessions if less than 24 hours have passed since you logged on the current session. 
See: https://core.telegram.org/method/account.resetAuthorization

Comment: Thanks mate, I will read now